Cannot start, remove or install Firefox after restoring using Timeshift
background, how i created this problem:
I replaced the drive in the PC. First I took a backup using Timeshift, then booted using live USB, then installed Timeshift to the Live boot, then restored from the external drive with the backup on it.
Booted into (X)ubuntu and everything (but not quite) appears to work.
All apps except Firefox start and function as expected.
Firefox would not start. Nor could I remove it using command line or Software app.
This was originally because of a readonly filesystem error at /var/snap/firefox/common/hunspell/anything.aff
So I unmounted that and was able to remove FF, but now I can't re-install it using snap or apt (apt points to the snap annoyingly).
sudo snap remove firefox 
> snap "firefox" is not installed

snap install firefox 
> error cannot perform following tasks: 
Run configure hook of "firefox" snap if present (run hook "configure":
 cannot locate base snap core22: no such file or directory)  

sudo apt install firefox  

that last attempt returns the same error as 'snap install' but with more info:
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox[..version].deb (--unpack)
I tried installing other software using apt, and that works fine. So I don't think there's a dpkg or snap or apt config error.
What to do?

Does this answer your question? Cannot repair the broken snap core22 on Ubuntu 22.04

Was install of FF the snap or .deb? Restore method would be different.

@oldfred I tried both. Could not get either snap or apt to work, although I never tried downloading a .deb or building from scratch, but apt now points to the snap as I said.

@guiverc it was 24.04 aka current release at time of writing. FF version = latest.

They made it bit ore difficult to install FF as .deb. Even snaptic now installs the snap version. You also have to reset priorities as shown or it will reinstall the Firefox snap.https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

It's always after you write it out on these forums that you find the answer.
Cannot repair the broken snap core22 on Ubuntu 22.04
That thread had the answer.
Problem solved by:
sudo snap refresh --beta core22  

Core22 seems to be a dep FF relies on, I thought the point of snaps was to be a sandboxed package with all deps in the box. Idk.
sudo snap refresh --stable core22  

Because "sudo snap refresh beta22" just tells me that core22 is latest.
As the answer in that other askUbuntu thread says, change from stable to beta, then back again and it updates.
snap install firefox  

works.
